# Stack Overflow is great for highlighting to you how to fix your own code

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I had been trying to solve a problem in my JavaScript web application for an hour or so, when I decided to ask the community for advice.

After spending 20 minutes or so explaining my problem and formatting the code nicely* I noticed the problem in the code.

Just framing my question simply and removing unnecessary code, highlighted the problem staring at me in the face.

Has anybody else had this experience, and if so do you have a process you use to "remove the trees to see the wood" outside of Stack Overflow?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: Not enough people are doing this…

Comment: That's one of the big reasons we ask for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - a lot of times just making one it will highlight where the error is. That page also includes a link to Eric Lippert's excellent write-up on [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: There's a reason I have 4 ducks at my desk.. the hippo and turtle? Not so much.

Comment: I'm glad this has been your experience.  From my point of view, all to often questions will be asked and this process will begin, and then someone will simply provide an answer.  This disuades (in my opinion) the authors from learning to investigate their questions and truely learn to debug.  After all, why learn to fish when there's a community handing out fish?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a common enough experience, and a variation of what's commonly called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

The process of asking a question involves staring at your problem from a different angle, to be able to explain it properly and hopefully anticipate the questions that potential helpers may have about your issue.

This forces you through a different evaluation process than the one you were following up to that point, and many, many, many times it ends up with you self-solving your issue.

Ducky does it again, and we all win.

That's why it's so important to spend a non-trivial amount of time and effort building up a question. Not only is it more likely one will get better answers if finally posted, but the likelihood of one solving the original issue by going through this is not to be ignored.

You can read more about [this in this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) by one of the site's founders.

Comment: More than anything, it forces you to examine your assumptions.  "This problem happens when `a` is set to `12`"...wait, does it, though?  Did I ever check that `a` was really set to `12` here?  

Answer (score 9):

Another very helpful part is insisting on an MCVE. Breaking down the code really to the minimal reproducible part often makes the mistake obvious, too.

The downside is, that some people simply abandon the question and leave the site after they have found their solution this way, while other users keep speculating and asking for details on the question itself.

Comment: An MCVE is not compatible with minimum-effort users.

Comment: Yes the title would be more clearly "SO *historical question quality standard* is great for highlighting to you how to fix your own code". But SO Inc management won't better inform new users of that.

Answer (score 8):

Yep.

A dozen times or more, I have been halfway through writing out a question on Stack Overflow and the solution has presented itself.

If (to my mind) it's a particularly good question, I am always caught between jubilation and disappointment.

Comment: If it is particularly good question, that has not been asked before, then it would probably make sense that you post anyway and self answer such question.

Comment: Hah. I've done that once or twice, too.

Answer (score 0):

Every. Single. Time. ... as linked above (and in comments under your question), it is the rubber duck approach. I have probably drafter 150+ questions that I end up hitting ctrl-A, delete on because it solves the issue.

The reason there are so many "me too" answers and comments is because this is a normal thing to go through and it will happen more and more as you get experience programming. It will even become less and less language specific. As you get the meta-concepts of programming, you will need others less often to debug your code - though it will never go away completely (just like a professional author doesn't proofread/edit their own copy). Even with a new language it isn't so much that you didn't know how to do something, but is instead that you just overlooked something, or typo-ed on syntax or any number of other things that boil down to mistakes you can solve yourself.

With new languages these often get sorted with the minimal reproducible example. With languages I have experience with I tend to find the issue before I get to the MCVE. You mileage may vary but probably not by much.